# SSkeychain, how to store a NSArray

Tags: ios, xcode

In a different question I was suggested to use SSKeychain, and after searching the web it seems that SSKeychain is the preferred method for working with Keychain.

It is very hard to find code examples, and the ones there is just stores a string, which is a password.

How would you go about saving and retrieving a NSArray with SSKeychain, when you have several keys you wanna store in the keychain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: http://github.com/granoff/Lockbox. It's a project I built to store data securely in the keychain, which has the added advantage of surviving an app being deleted and re-installed.

This is drop in class. It just works.

**EDIT:** *Now* it just works. I think something about Xcode 4.5 got more strict than when I originally developed Lockbox. Thanks to a contribution from a forked version, it is again simply a "drop and go" solution.

Comment: Looks interesting. I do not have to add all kinds of texts license wise to show my users right? And does it work with ARC?

Comment: @Jacob if you have a look at the commit messages and the code, you see that it uses ARC.

Comment: Sorry, but I just found some posts where some other people said it did not, so just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: @Jacob: The code "just works" whether you are using ARC or not. ARC is not a requirement for your project to be able to use Lockbox. As for the license, read the LICENSE file. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Jacob Also, there's a solution for storing arrays using `SSkeychain`, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: I just dropped the m and h files into my project, but get 10 errors: Cast of C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast

Comment: Hmm.... that should be handled automagically. Weird.

Comment: Would like to use Lockbox, since it seems to be easier method calls for what I wanna do. Any idear how to fix this issue?

Comment: Those errors suggest something weird related to ARC settings, but honestly, the code should compile with or without ARC. So I am a little stumped. Is your project using ARC, or not? Let's start there.

Comment: I think I might have told it to add the files to target when adding the files. Now I did not do that and no errors came until I started using Lockbox. Now I get _OBJC_CLASS_$_Lockbox and linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when I try to build

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is. Could be that Xcode4.5 is stricter than previous versions of Xcode, under which I developed Lockbox originally. I'll get a fix up soon.

Comment: No, you have to have them included in the project, otherwise you get that linker error. :-)

Comment: Okay, so I did not do anything wrong :) Not to push you, but when do you think that will be, since I need to get elements in the keychain and the app out fast. hehe

Comment: I just pushed up a fix. Also, be sure you add `Security.framework` to your project.

Comment: Now it is building without any problems. Thanks alot for the help

Comment: No problem. Glad you're off and running!

Comment: well done @MarkGranoff! I didn't try yet - but gonna do looks promising